# New user added to msdb in SQL throwing The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object error in VS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have added an update trigger to one of the tables in my database which basically calls the sp_update_schedule stored procedure in msdb database.

So the user I am accessing with from Visual Studio, I have given the user datareader, datawriter and ddladmin permissions. I tried to login in sql as that user and ran the trigger and it works fine while also updating the schedule table in msdb using the sp_update_schedule.

However when I run it from the web application,while the update to the table is working, the trigger fails with the following error

> "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_update_schedule', database 'msdb', schema dbo"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User must be sysadmin or in one of those roles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-jobschedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Permissions
By default, members of the sysadmin fixed server role can execute this stored procedure. Other users must be granted one of the following SQL Server Agent fixed database roles in the msdb database:

SQLAgentUserRole

SQLAgentReaderRole

SQLAgentOperatorRole

For details about the permissions of these roles, see SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles.

Only members of sysadmin can use this stored procedure to update job schedules that are owned by other users.